# How to delete session of The HTTP_USER_AGENT

Tags: php, session

In order to increase the security for the logged-in users, after the `session_start();` and assigning the other session variables, I also try to store the **HTTP_USER_AGENT** value, using `$_SESSION['agent'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);` for the `login.php` page.

Besides, in the `login.php` page, I redirect **logged-in users** to the home page if they try to visit it again without **logging it out** first, using the conditional like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['agent']) OR ($_SESSION['agent'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) ) {

//redirect to home page
header('location:http://index.php.com');
exit();
}
```

**The question is that** in my `logout.php` page I code the conditional like this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['agent']) OR ($_SESSION['agent'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) ) {

//Redirect to home page

}else{
$_SESSION = array(); // Destroy the variables.
session_destroy(); // Destroy the session itself.
setcookie (session_name(), '', time()-3600); // Destroy the cookie.
}
```

Then I came back to visit the `login.php` page again as a logged-in user (session has been set), it still redirected me to the home page.

Then I tried deleting the cookies in the FF browser, close it, then revisited the `login.php` page, it still redirected me.

Do you know what I was wrong or missing?

**NOTE: I have no problem to destroy the session if not storing **the HTTP_USER_AGENT**

Comment: change

    if (isset($_SESSION['agent']) OR ($_SESSION['agent'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) )


to


    if (isset($_SESSION['agent']) OR ($_SESSION['agent'] == md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) )

Comment: On your login.php I think you are confusing setting a variable (`=`) and comparing a variable (`==`).

Comment: Mind that anybody how can capture the session id has also access to all other headers including the user agent. This doesn't improve security.

Answer (score 1):

You have an assignment where you want to check.

Change:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['agent']) OR ($_SESSION['agent'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) ) {
```

to

```
if (isset($_SESSION['agent']) OR ($_SESSION['agent'] == md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) ) {
```

off topic security tip(maybe helpfull):

```
public function Start_Secure_Session()
{
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);

    // Gets current cookies params
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();

    // Set Cookie Params
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],      $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $this->isHTTPS, $this-  >deny_java_session_id);
    // Sets the session name
    session_name($this->session_name);

    // Start the php session
    session_start();

    // If new session or expired, generate new id
    if (!isset($_SESSION['new_session']))
    {
        $_SESSION['new_session'] = "true";

        // regenerate the session, delete the old one.
        session_regenerate_id(true);
    }
}
```